# Should linked many to many objects be written both in Realm?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

For example I have

```
class A : Object
{
     let bList List<B> = List<B>()
}

class B : Object
{
    let aList List<A> = List<A>()
}
```

And then somewhere in my networking part I do something like

```
let bItems : [B] = []
let a : A = A()

a.bList.appendContentsOf(bItems)
bItems.forEach({$0.aList.append(a)})
```

When I save to Realm, do I have to write both of them? Or writing just "a" should be enough? Like this:

```
let realm : Realm = try Realm()

try realm.write({ () -> Void in
    realm.add(a, update: true)
})
```

Or like this:

```
let realm : Realm = try Realm()

try realm.write({ () -> Void in
    realm.add(a, update: true)
    realm.add(bList, update : true)
})
```

p.s. Especially taking into consideration that I really need the "update" feature. Which means both A objects and B objects my already exist and may just need an update over their properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got one Realm `Object` containing a list of child objects, Realm is capable of performing a reverse look-up on your behalf using the `Object().linkingObjects(_:forProperty:)` method.

For example, to find out which instances of `A` and instance of `B` is a child of.

```
let aParentObject = bItem.linkingObjects(A.self, forProperty: "bList")
```

You certainly can maintain a list in both directions like that, but it's definitely a lot more work. ;)

Comment: Got ya) so you mean it automatically saves all the children present at the moment of realm.write. without need to write them separately. This was my doubt..